# What is the difference between `terraform apply` vs. `terraform destroy` when removing resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I managed AWS rds instance on Terraform, but the instance is no longer needed so I removed all `.tf` files for that instance.
In this case, I think I can perform `terraform destroy`, but do I need to trigger `terraform apply` before that, or only one of these is enough? I don't fully understand the difference of those two commands when removing resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[terraform destroy](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/destroy.html) is used to delete/destroy **all resources** that you managed by your TF files. In contrast, [terraform apply](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html) is used to apply changes to your TF controlled infrastructure. This means that only **selected** resources will be changed (or removed), not all.

In your case, since you removed `.tf` files associated with some instance, `terraform apply` will just destroy that instance. Other resources will not be affected. However, if you execute `terraform destroy` everything will be removed, including the instance and anything else that you have created.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clear explanation!

Comment: @lipsum No problem. Glad I could help.